# How can you access a token from strtok()?

Tags: c++, string, char, c-strings

Suppose you tokenize the following string "Hello World" with the separator being space, you'd get the following:

```
Hello
World
```

For example, if I wanted to count every vowel from the first token ("Hello"), how would I do that? How would I work with ONLY the first token? Is there a way you can do this?

Comment: it would work the same way if "Hello" was just a single `std::string` by itself. All strings are alike, whether they came from `strtok` or have some other origin. What does your question have to do with `strtok`, this is quite unclear?

Comment: Note that in the English language 'y' is sometimes a vowel and sometimes it isn't depending on how it's pronounced which depends on context. Thus, calculating vowels in English is quite difficult and not possible without some natural language processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you MUST use strtok(), then remember that strtok() is a C call that contains references to internally defined global variables.

When you call strtok(), it returns a pointer to the first token AND it modifies the source string by injecting null characters.

That means you can use that returned pointer as if it was its own string.

```
char * token = strtok("Hello\nWorld", "\n");
size_t vowelCount = strcspn ( token, "aeiouyAEIOUY" );
```